# is there a way to change the class on a div by clicking on an input button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styling

I have a div that I want hidden on page load. The class name on the div is "messages-hide"

When I click on a submit button, I want to change the class on that div to "messages-show".

My HTML is:

```
<div class="messages-hide"></div>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send the request" />
```

My CSS is:

```
.messages-hide {
    display: none;
}

.messages-show {
    display: block;
}
```

The submit button works as is, but it's not changing the class (obviously).

I'm assuming this is fairly simple using Javascript or jQuery, but I don't know where to begin.

I've found several solutions that look like they should work, but nothing that works specifically with an input/submit button. I've already spent hours on this. Figure it's time to ask for help...

I'm open to anything that will work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated... thanks!

Comment: *I've found several solutions that look like they should work, but nothing that works specifically with an input/submit button. I've already spent hours on this.* What have you tried? Please include your attempts with your question. Are you familiar with event listeners?

Comment: Easiest way is use an [Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and use jQuery's [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Comment: `div.classList.remove("messages-hide");` to remove a class then `div.classList.add("messages-hideshow);` to add a class to your element. All this while inside an eventListener of course

Comment: If the submit button is in a form, clicking it will submit the form. This reloads the page, so any class changes you make will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

The simplest way in my opinion is have a default class lets call it `messages`. And in that class is display none.

Then have a class called `show` that is display block.

Then on click of your button simply add the show class to the messages div.

However, one note is if its a submit button in a form, once the form reloads the page the messages will be hidden again. Unless you have more going on in your javascript submit/click function that you haven't posted.

**Update**
If you want to show the messages div after page load, then you can use localStorage.getItem and localStorage.setItem.

Due to the limitations in the snippet tool, I can't enable localStorage. But for your implementation, just uncomment those lines.

```js
const btnSubmit = document.querySelector("#btnSubmit");
const messages = document.querySelector(".messages");

//const showMsgs = (localStorage.getItem("showMsgs"))

//if(showMsgs)messages.classList.add("show")

btnSubmit.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  messages.classList.add("show")
//  localStorage.setItem("showMsgs",1)
});
```

```css
.messages{
    display: none;
}

.messages.show{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages">MESSAGES</div>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send the request" />
```

Comment: Yes, I'll need the .show class to be there after the submit as well.

Comment: @STEVEMTNO I updated my code and the text in my answer

Comment: Just tried that. Uncommented the localStorage lines, still not working. no errors in the console..

.messages is showing display: none in devtools

Comment: I would post a jsfiddle/snippet with your updated code because I tested mine and it does work

Comment: unfortunately, i can't post any more of the code... and i don't have a jsfiddle acct (or know how to use it)...

Comment: @STEVEMTNO you can update your question with the updated coded

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to handle the click event of the submit button and change the class name of the div with the class "messages-hide" to "messages-show". Make sure to add some CSS to control the visibility of the div based on its class.

Here's a full example:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Toggle Message</title>
    <style>
        .messages-hide {
            display: none;
        }
        .messages-show {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="messages-hide">Your message goes here.</div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send the request" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (script.js):

```
document.getElementById('btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var div = document.querySelector('.messages-hide');
  if (div) {
    div.className = 'messages-show';
  }
});
```

This code will switch the class of the div from "messages-hide" to "messages-show" when the submit button is clicked, and your message will become visible if it's hidden. Make sure the CSS is set up to hide the "messages-hide" class and show the "messages-show" class as demonstrated above.

You can also use a toggle-like behavior to show and hide the div on successive clicks of the submit button. You can achieve this by checking the current class and then changing it accordingly.

Here's the updated JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById('btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var div = document.querySelector('.messages-hide') || document.querySelector('.messages-show');
  if (div) {
    if (div.className === 'messages-hide') {
      div.className = 'messages-show';
    } else {
      div.className = 'messages-hide';
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

mdn says:

> Note that the submit event fires on the  element itself, and not on any  or  inside it. However, the SubmitEvent which is sent to indicate the form's submit action has been triggered includes a submitter property, which is the button that was invoked to trigger the submit request.

So what you need to do is to watch for the submit event on the form. Assuming your form has an id of "myForm," you can do something like this in jquery:

```
$("#myForm").on('submit', function() {
  $(".message-hide").addClass("message-show");
  $(".message-hide").removeClass("message-hide");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but you can use jQuery code like this using `.toggle()`:

```js
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div.message').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message" style="display:none;">Message</div>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send the request" />
```